# Java + Selenium - Unable to Click Dropdown(Not a Select dropdown) and Select a Value from the drop down

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

In JAVA Selenium - I am not able to click the dropdown and select a value from it, this is not a select dropdown. This is a saleforce site. I have seen it working 1 in 10 executions but not getting it work consistently.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbiUN.png)
This is the HTML for the dropdown and it is not getting clicked, the xpath for the dropdown used is

```
//*[@data-name='billingRoadType']//*[name()='lightning-base-combobox']//button
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVcUP.png)
This is the HTML for the dropdown values. the xpath for the dropdown value used is

//*[@data-name='billingRoadType']//*[@data-value='Otro']

Have tried JavaScript executor, Action class and click sometimes the JSExecutor works but that is like 1 in 10 times.The application is in salesforce. Have tried explicit waits also but not working

Getting NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@data-name='billingRoadType']//*[@data-value='Otro']"}

Comment: Can you share URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @qatesterbecomingprogrammer and @Pradheep Raaj

This issue was resolved by the following from the root tag(webruntime-app) i had to write the xpath or css, we could find it from document.querySelector was sometimes working and other times it was not working in the browser.

Therefore tried writing the xpath from the root to make it work. Thanks for your suggestions and inputs.

```
     WebElement app = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("webruntime-app"));
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     app.findElement(By.cssSelector(".slds-combobox__form-element.slds-input-has- 
     icon.slds-input-has-icon_right button"));
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     app.findElement(By.cssSelector("[part='combobox'] [title='Horeca 
     diurno']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this button / link is placed in url which you opens fresh and click it?
If yes pls check whether all the components are loaded when the page is loaded. May be there is any component which loads as ajax and may be causing a interruption.
And pls post the console dom of the button

Comment: Hi Pradheep - It is there in the first image in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply waits, two times... One for displaying and the other for clickable.

```
String valueXpath = "//[@data-value='Otro']"
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(valueXpath)));

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(valueXpath)));

WebElement dropDownValueToBeSelected = driver.findElement(By.xpath, valueXpath);
dropDownValueToBeSelected.click();
```

**Remember, don't initialize webelement, before it gets displayed.**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion that not to initialize weblement before it is displayed.

Element is not visible till i click on the dropdown, so it fails in the step visibilityOfElementLocated .. 

But I have used JScript Executor with Action Class and it works but not consistent...

Comment: @VenkatramAyyer have you clicked on drop down button?

Comment: qatesterbecomingprogrammer - Sometimes it clicks some time it does not click. That is the thing. If it clicks than it selects the value and it is done

Comment: Then you have to apply two same waits on drop down as well.

Comment: Added more wait but same result cannot see the dropdown clicked each time.